# Prompt the user to download an excel file?

Tags: php

I am trying to prompt the user to download PDF file using fpdf library which works, but when I try the same for Excel, it does not prompt the user but instead forces to download the file automatically. How do I use prompt command before downloading?

```
        $fileName = "Excel_".date('Y_m_d').".xls";
        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
        echo $output;
```

Comment: `header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");`  try this

Comment: @aviboy2006 I tried, it still downloads automatically without asking the user to download.

Comment: for pdf generally browser understand format it can view in browser also. for excel case is different. that why its getting automatically downloaded. `mimetype` one attribute

Comment: Yes I thought so but there could be a way to prompt it?

Comment: you have to write javascript prompt box. it can get done by default

Comment: It is not likely that you will achieve what you are trying to do. What a browser does with files is controlled by the end user and you can't change what they have decided.